# R - values of x between 3 and 7

Tags: r, statistics

I'm starting to learn R, as it's needed for work. I have never done statistical work, so I'm a bit lost.

I'm looking to get the value of x between two numbers.

So, for example, the range is 3:7 I need to print 4,5,6

I have tried

```
    x <- 3:7
    x[x>3 && x<7]
```

and

```
x <- 3
v <- 7
cbind(x, findInterval(x, v))
```

Any advice/guidelines

Comment: In the first you have a typo, there's a `x`missing. And use the vectorized and, `&`. `x[x > 3 & x < 7]`. PS: read the file `R-intro.pdf` that comes with your installation of `R`.

Comment: Thanks very much @RuiBarradas

Answer (score 1):

An option is `between` from `data.table`

```
x[data.table::between(x, 3, 7, incbounds = FALSE)]
#[1] 4 5 6
```